# Override application-wide style with a template in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, templates, listbox, styles, listboxitem

I have a Silverlight application where I have styled my listboxes. This is a part of the style of the ListBoxItem, which is application-wide:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ListBoxItemGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource MouseOverColorBrush}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Now I have another listbox where I want nothing to happen when the user hovers over the ListBoxItem. I have tried this:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
</VisualStateGroup>
```

But that doesn't seem to work. How can I override the default, application-wide style? I'm not sure if it is relevant, but the application-wide style is a Style, while my 'special' listbox has a Template for its ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I had to give the container a style:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding TheItems}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TheLineStyle}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TheItemTemplate}"></ListBox>


<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="TheLineStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```